# How to reset code formatting to default settings in visual studio? (Without having to reset all my settings)

Tags: visual-studio

I am having problems editing powershell files in visual studio. The text that are meant to be comments show in large green text that make it very hard to read. I have no idea how it got this way. It is possible it may be an extention causing the problem. But the first step is to try reset it to defaults...

So how do I do that without resetting all my settings? (or if anyone else can suggest a different solution I am all ears)

Below is a screenshot of what I see...
[image]

Comment: I would take a look at coderush settings from devexpress for your specific case, as it probably overrides VS settings.

Comment: Bingo! That was it. It's something to do with coderush. I just disabled it. And it is now working properly....so that has narrowed it down a fair bit....I shall return with an answer once I have done more exploring..thank you.

Comment: A friendly advice, is to have knowledge of the tools you are using and checking the settings.


First learn VS (it does so many things out of the box that people often use plugins for build in functionality), then each extension installed should have a solid knowledge of what it is doing, when and possible other settings to customize your needs.

Comment: Thankyou. Not too concerned about it, but fixed it anyway...buy in terms of having knowledge of the tools we use. I guess, you and I both know that's impossible :) One brain cannot keep up with 10,000 working in a corporate environment :)

Comment: You would be surprised how much an online video of 6h about visual studio paid back by knowing the existence of the functionality when it was needed. But yeah, it's pretty tough when you are getting started. But afterwards you won't dedicate time for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the fonts and colors for the editor under Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors => "Use Defaults" (top right).

Comment: Found it. Tried it. Dang. It didn't solve the problem. It must be an extension doing it then. This helps me get to the next step of searching. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was DevExpress' Coderush addon causing the problem. It is actually the 'RichComments' feature that is causing the issue [image: Toggle Rich Comments]

I must have accidentally click on the toolbar option without realising. Now I know.

To make the issue go away, one just has to toggle the button on the toolbox.